# Do the procs of PvP Items trigger in PVE?

Tags: star-wars-the-old-republic

I bought a PvP Relic for my tank, for use in PvE. After using it for a while, I never actually recognized any buffs coming from it, but I might have just overlooked it in the heat of the battle.

So do PvP Relics actually trigger in a PvE Environment?

The description does not give it away, but PvE Relics have a note that it cannot be activated in a PvP Combat. So there might be a catch here.

[image: Screenshot of item in question]

Comment: Seems easy to test: pull up your character window, let a 40ish enemy beat on you, and watch your defense to see if it changes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can use PvP Relics for PvE.

The Obroan relics are actually pretty good compared to the PvE relics. At this point the Dread Forged relics are the BiS relics. After that comes the Obroan(pvp) Relic.

Answer (score 3):

I quit before lvl 55 was the cap, but unless it is actually stated in the description, it should work in a PvE environment.
In the old days most people were using PvP relics to raid because they were a lot better then the PvE ones.
Then BioWare ofcourse started making decent PvE relics.

I cant provide you with any proof to back this up, but they worked in the past and i always kept my client up to date and kept an eye on the weekly patches notes because i sometimes play casually,i never recall seeing a patch that said PvP relics were for PvP only.